# Get image from mysql database and display them on flask website

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, web

I am trying to get an image which i have on my mysql database to show on my website. Here is a picture of the problem. [image: error]   And this is only a small part of the image after i get it from the database.[image]
I managed to display an image on the website which was opened as a file after i converted it. But my goal is to be able to open it as it's saved on the database.
I did that with this code

```
        import mysql.connector
        import base64
        from PIL import Image
        import io
        
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                    host='192.168.0.23',
                    user='pi',
                    passwd='1234',
                    database='Test',
                )
        
        cursor = mydb.cursor()
        query = 'SELECT picture FROM Universities WHERE ID=21'
        cursor.execute(query)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        image = data[0][0]
        binary_data = base64.b64decode(image)
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(binary_data))
```

app.py

```
@app.route("/search", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def search_page():

if request.method == "POST":
    major = request.form["major"]
    country = request.form["country"]
    price = request.form["price"]
    universities = search_universities(country, major, price)
    #print(universities)
    if universities != []:
        
        import base64
        from PIL import Image
        import io

        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                    host='192.168.0.23',
                    user='pi',
                    passwd='1234',
                    database='Test',
                )

        cursor = mydb.cursor()
        query = 'SELECT picture FROM Universities WHERE ID=22'
        cursor.execute(query)
        data = cursor.fetchall()

        image = data[0][0]

        binary_data = base64.b64decode(image)


        return render_template('result.html', text1 = universities, img_data=binary_data('utf-8', 'ignore'))
    else:
        return render_template('result.html')
return render_template('search.html')
```

result.html

```
  {% extends "base.html" %}
   {% block title %} Search {% endblock %}
   {% block style %}{% endblock %}
  {% block body %}


 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Image</title>
    </head>

    <h1 align="center">Resluts</h1>
    {% for text in text1 %}
     <div class="card" id = "element1">
    <img id="picture" src="data:image/png;base64,{{ img_data }}" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%; max- 
     height: 60vh;">
    <div class="container">

    <h4><b>Name: {{ text[0] }}</b></h4>
    <p>Country: {{ text[1]}}</p>
    <p>Major: {{ text[2] }}</p>
    <p>Estemated price: {{ text[3] }}</p>
    <p>link: {{ text[4] }}</p>

     </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
   <div class="card" id = "element1">
   <img src={{url_for('static', filename='pictures/uni2.png')}} alt="Avatar" style="width:20%">
   <div class="container">
  
      <h4><b>Name: </b></h4>
      <p>Country: </p>
      <p>Major: </p>
      <p>Estemated price: </p>
      <p>link: </p>
  
  </div>
  </div>

<p>Here is my variable: {{ text1 }}</p>


  {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert it from a bytes object to a string

```py
import base64
image = base64.b64encode(Image.open(io.BytesIO(binary_data)))
```

I'm unsure if this is the right code, so please let me know what works for you.

Looking at other examples this might be the right code

```py
import base64
image = base64.b64encode(io.BytesIO(binary_data).getvalue())
```

Comment: if i remove this  ('utf-8', 'ignore') this is the result https://prnt.sc/11anfz4

Comment: you need to prepend the image base64 string with the following `data:image/png;base64,`

code for this would look like the following image = "data:image/png;base64,%s"%image

Comment: or this image = "data:image/png;base64,"+image

Comment: did this work? if so please mark the question as answered

Answer (score 0):

You're using this kind of [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) to represent the image.  `data:image/png;base64,ddddddd`.

It calls for the data (`dddddd` in my example) to be base64-encoded.

But the line `binary_data = base64.b64decode(image)` of your program takes the base64 data from your database and changes it to binary.  Try skipping that step. Do this.

```
return render_template('result.html', text1 = universities, img_data=image)
```